# Editing compound key to primary key

Tags: mysql

Currently I have two columns  ( both as Null initially ) which are Primary Key in the Ordinal Column Info ( which means its a compound / composite key right )

I want to edit this table to only retain one column as key
Tried the following command :

```
ALTER TABLE observations DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(*column_name*);
```

Getting this error :

```
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Not sure you can run both the drop and add in the same command, try doing it as two commands: `ALTER TABLE observations DROP PRIMARY KEY; ALTER TABLE observations ADD PRIMARY KEY(*column_name*);`

Comment: Can you add your table structure to your post please?